# How to get existing database row from exists-rule of a laravel validator?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

How can I get the value, that was found with  `exists` rule of a `Validator`?

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'invite' => 'required|max:30|exists:invites,code',
]);
```

I don't want to make a second request to a database, it is already done by the validator.

```
Invite::where('code', $value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that. An `exists` statement returns a boolean. That's what the `exists` rule does.

The best thing you can do here, in my opinion is removing the `exists` rule from the validator, and just after the validation passes, you query for the invite. If it returns `null`, then manually handle the `abort()`.

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'invite' => 'required|max:30',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('some/route')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    } 
    // now check for existance
    else if (! $invite = Invite::where('code', $request->code)->first()) {
        return abort(404, 'Invitation not found');
    }

    $invite->someMethod();
```

Comment: Zend framework stores the row inside the validator, I've expected that laravel does the same.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan even if it could store the value, the sql query for the rule `exists` returns a boolean. You can always create your own validation rules from a service provider, but I'd suggest the method I wrote instead.

Comment: Where is the query creating? Haven't found it in validator code

Comment: can you help to find the code responsible for creating the query?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan You can see how the query is built in [here](https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/master/Rules/Exists.php) (browse the repo) but that's not the way you should address this. Sometimes we over-complicate things with premature optimization. If you're still that concerned about this, I can help you writting a custom validation rule (which won't be better than the example I provided above).